# Apache Thrift generated Python enum field not associated with enum class

Tags: python, enums, thrift

I'm working with Thrift 0.17 and having an issue with the way that Thrift is generating my enum fields. The field is listed as an I32 (which is expected) and there is a class that's generated which has fields_to_values and values_to_fields, *but* there's no link between the enum field and the enum class.

Unfortunately, the way my enum fields are stored in BigQuery is by the string value. When I try to put that data into Thrift objects, I have no way to automatically associate each I32 enum field with the respective class that it's supposed to be. So I may have `my_enum_field_one`:I32 and `my_enum_field_two`:I32 as well as `EnumClassOne` and `EnumClassTwo` but I don't have any reference on which might belong to which within the generated Python.

It seems to be the same issue that was mentioned in [this post](https://user.thrift.apache.narkive.com/4WXPh5mx/introspection-of-thrift-enums-in-python) 10 years ago, which references [this JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2059), which leads to this [merged PR](https://github.com/apache/thrift/pull/2489) which was merged prior to the release of version 0.17, so I don't *believe* it fixed the issue- or maybe I'm just missing something!

Any guidance on existing fixes or workarounds would be super appreciated!

I've been looking at the `spec_args` and looking at the generated thrift `ttypes.py` file expecting to find some reference to the enum class name, but the only reference I've been able to find to my enum classes are the class definitions themselves.

Answer (score 0):

To update, I discovered the compiler flag for using python 3.4 style enums and was able to generate enums properly with `thrift --gen py:enum`